# Работа со списками и структурами

Tags: c#

Условие:

> С помощью структур (списка) решить: Набор материалов, имеющихся на
>   складе, с разбивкой по виду товара. Количество видов товаров и штук
>   каждого товара задать самостоятельно. Составить модуль формирования
>   двух новых списков из исходного списка товаров. В первый список
>   попадают номера товаров меньше некоторого заданного, во второй —
>   больше

Проблема в "Case 3". То есть я хочу сравнить весь изначальный список товаров с заданным числом "int Pod" и занести все товары которые больше заданного "Pod" в новый list. Не могу понять, что я делаю не так.

Все товары которые больше заданного "Pod", заносятся в List bolshe, товары которые меньше заданного "Pod" заносятся в List menshe

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace lab9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            List<string> nomer1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> menshe = new List<string>();
            List<string> bolshe = new List<string>();
            while (true)
            {

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("1) Добавление нового товара");
                Console.WriteLine("2) Вывод всех товаров");
                Console.WriteLine("3) Вывод товаров, которые выше указанного числа");
                Console.WriteLine("4) Выход");

                int nav = 0;
                try
                {
                    nav = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка!");
                }

                switch (nav)
                {
                    case 1:
                        st BIP; string temp = null; string nomer2 = null;

                        Console.Write("Введите номер товара: ");
                        nomer2 += "1) Номер: " + (BIP.nomer = Console.ReadLine()) + "\n";

                        Console.Write("Введите количество товара: ");
                        temp += "2) Количество: " + (BIP.kolichestvo = Console.ReadLine()) + "\n";

                        Console.Write("Введите наименование товара: ");
                        temp += "3) Наименование: " + (BIP.naimenovanie = Console.ReadLine()) + "\n";

                        list.Add(nomer2 + temp);
                        nomer1.Add(nomer2);

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        foreach (string i in list)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(i);
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Введите число для вывода: ");
                        int pod = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (nomer1[j] > pod)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(list[j]);
                            }
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    case 4: return;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct st
    {
        public string nomer;
        public string kolichestvo;
        public string naimenovanie;
    }

}
```

Comment: Проблему решил.

Comment: А вы уже ООП проходили? Что такое класс, наследование и проч. знаете?

Answer (score 0):

В строке `if (nomer1[j] > pod)` вы сравниваете строку с числом, что в c# запрещено

Плюс в списке `nomer` вы храните строки вида "Номер: n", поэтому простого преобразования типа для сравнения будет мало.

Храните в списке или только числа, используя тип данных `int`, или структуры `st` и тогда сравнивайте  `if (nomer1[j].nomer > pod)`